# Why can't I open the context menu for Flash videos in Chrome on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, google-chrome, flash

I'm trying to change the "quality" to low of a Hulu video so I can full screen it with out it being choppy but right click does nothing. When I right click in firefox it brings up a menu.

I'm running Chrome on Ubuntu 9.10, is any one else having this issue I tried Google and got nothing back. I use chrome as my main browser, I have to switch to firefox every time I watch Hulu videos.

Is there another way I cant change the quality of the flash video in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm Lucas' post.

To be able to get there (to the flash' help page), you have to be able to right-click on the flash application and get a menu or a dialog of some sort, but that's impossible, as Lance said earlier. That only happens (as far as I see it) in Chrome/Chromium (Linux Mint 9, Ubuntu 10.04, both amd64).

I got libflashplayer.so from adobe.com and replaced the default *.so, nothing, only firefox seems to notice the change by showing a different looking menu (not themed but with the same entries).

So, in short, Chrome/Chromium plays flash but right-clicking does *nothing*, no effect (thus, impossibility to change quality where it can be changed); in Firefox I get a menu, etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to Adobe, the only way to open/access the Flash settings is from the context menu.

[Flash Player Help](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help01.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with chromium (chrome) (lubuntu 13.10)

To be able to set some microphone settings in flash I did this:

- Download flash locally (I used the one from [this](http://www.adobe.com/swf/software/flash/about/mini_FMA_about_01.swf) link with wget)
- Load it in the browser and select settings (works both for firefox and chromium)